# OAuth 1.0 Generate Signature vs Postman Generate Signature

Tags: delphi, oauth, hmacsha1

I am writing a tool for the API of the Woocommerce plugin, which is one of the WordPress plugins. This tool uses the OAuth 1.0 system for authentication. When I set my request and send it via Postman, I can get my answer without any problem. My problem starts in the test application I wrote myself. When I create a signature with the same values ​​found in Postman, I find a different value from the Postman tool.

There are a number of base strings specified in the document. I encrypt this value with the specified key and create a signature. This signature is the same as the signature on the document. So, I can understand from here that my test tool is running smoothly. (https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#RFC2045 - Appendix A.5.2.  Calculating Signature Value
)

When I add the values ​​I get from Postman with the same tool to my test tool, I find different results. What came to my mind here was that the Postman tool added another parameter.

My Postman values ​​are:

[image]

I can operate with these values ​​without any problems. I add the same values ​​to the test application and get output;

[image]

Postman: tcBdkwXJL9Ad5RZFTQ36Vh34mYM=

My Test App: UJ2it9opCslL0Jjy7/T/C7Dw8rc=

I am developing the related test application with delphi. If you need the codes, I have shared them below.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 p1, p2, full: string;
begin
 p1 := cmbReqType.Text;

 p2 :=  TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(edit1.Text);
 p3 := 'oauth_consumer_key=' + oauth_consumer_key.Text
        + '&oauth_signature_method='+oauth_signature_method.Text
        + '&oauth_timestamp='+oauth_timestamp.Text +
        '&oauth_nonce=' + oauth_nonce.Text +
        '&oauth_version='+ oauth_version.Text;

 xp3 := p3;
 p3 := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(p3);
 full := p1 + '&' + p2 + '&' + p3;
 Memo1.Lines.Text := System.UTF8Encode(Trim(full));

 HMAC_SHA1 := THashSHA1.Create;
 Edit2.text := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(HMAC_SHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Trim(memo1.text)), TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Trim(secret_key.Text))));

 if Trim(Edit2.Text) = 'tcBdkwXJL9Ad5RZFTQ36Vh34mYM=' then
 begin
   ShowMessage('correct.');
 end else
     begin
       ShowMessage('not correct.');
     end;
end;
```

P.S: Forget the ugliness in the code. I coded it trivially :)

P.S: I leave similar topics below. Most do not respond to an answer.

1- [How do I view the raw signature Postman uses when it makes its OAuth requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514935/how-do-i-view-the-raw-signature-postman-uses-when-it-makes-its-oauth-requests)

2- [How does Postman Rest Client create Oauth Signature ? Unable to resolve Oauth_Signature in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760525/how-does-postman-rest-client-create-oauth-signature-unable-to-resolve-oauth-si)

...

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: `oauth_nonce` must come just after `oauth_consumer_key` (because params must be sorted by name).

Comment: Oliver; I can't tell you how happy I am right now. I am thankful to you. I solved the problem with your correction and an additional situation I added. The first step was to change the order as you said. Well, I couldn't understand why they avoided this situation in the examples given in the documents. Another fix was that I added an "&" next to the "secret key". The reason for this is that oauth_token and secret key should be side by side. Since I didn't have any tokens, the merge symbol (&) was enough. E.g. `cs_9388....58aa464845&` . If you add it as an answer I'd like to approve and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building the [Signature Base String](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor13), OAuth1 requires that parameters be sorted by name. In your case, it means that `oauth_nonce` must come just after `oauth_consumer_key`.

Additionally, when computing the [HMAC](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor15), the key must include both the Consumer Secret and the Token Secret, separated by an `&`, even if the token is empty. Since you have no token, you must append an `&` to your secret.